# How to send message to all agents in population?

Tags: anylogic

I need to send message to all students in population from monthly event.

[image: Main agent]

But (I guess) it`s not possible to use `sendToAll()`
method in this case, because event is declared inside of another enviroment.

I know how to send message to specific agent through using `students.random()` as a second argument in `send()`
method, but is it possible to send message to all agents?

Comment: you can always loop over the agent list and send the message

Answer (score 0):

This loops across all students in the population and sends them a message:

```
for (Student currentStudent : students) {
    send("Hey", currentStudent);
}
```